# Algorithim to detect outliers from a curve

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the two figures below.

[image]

[image]

Visually, I can detect that several data points were out of place compared to the overall shape of the curve. What are some good suggestions for detecting these points and reconciling their values so that they fit in with the rest of the data points?

Comment: Significant jumps in value. Also, this should be tagged with `python` not `python-3.x`.

Comment: You can use `numpy.diff` and take the median of the displacements, then mark or modify anything that is some threshold larger than the median

Comment: Simply filter on first absolute difference criterion that would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole Change Point Detection
literature on this topic.

Recommend that you `import`
[ruptures](https://pypi.org/project/ruptures).

It formulates this problem in this way:

- There was a Generative Process out in the world, using certain model parameters.
- At some point the parameters changed, so the process outputs also changed.
- Wrapping a cost function around changes, what is the minimum set of Change Points that best explains what we observed?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't think your problem is actually detecting *outliers*, based on the example you provided it looks like you are try to minimize bias or scale shifts in a time series (I'd recommend updating your question title so that others could find this question).

So you've asked two separate questions: how to identify discontinuities in your signal and then how to rectify it. As posted in the comments, `np.diff` would be a good solution for identifying the edges of your discontinuities.

In terms of rectifying the data, here are a few solutions that you could try out, depending on your data:

**Method 1**: If a simple vertical shift would suffice, then use the derivative of the adjacent "good" data to figure out how far to vertically shift the "bad" data

**Method 2**: If vertical shifting isn't accurate enough (perhaps there is a different slope to your "bad" data), then find the derivatives on either side of the "bad" data and interpolate them, then apply those interpolated shifts

**Method 3**: Remove the "bad" data and try to find a sufficient polynomial fit, and then use that to estimate the missing data.

**Note**: For situations where the "bad" data is located at the edge of your dataset (as in your upper image), you'll only be able to use a version of Method 1

In this example I made a simple signal with two shifted sections. You can see in the first plot how spikes in `np.diff` can locate the edges of the shifted parts. Here is some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## make an arbitrary signal curve
x = np.arange(0,20,0.1)
f1 = .1
f2 = .12
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*x) + np.sin(np.pi*f2*x)


##------------------
## add "jumps" in signal
y[30:50] = y[30:50] - 0.3
y[120:130] = y[120:130] + np.linspace(1,1.3,10)

## compute the first derivative to identify jumps
deriv = np.diff(y)

## find index locations of jumps
jump_threshold = 0.2
jump_idxs = np.where(np.abs(deriv)>jump_threshold)[0]



##------------------
## METHOD 1
## use adjacent derivatives to rectify data
deriv_match1 = deriv[jump_idxs[0]-1]
deriv_match2 = deriv[jump_idxs[2]-1]

## find the vertical shift amount required to satisfy the average derivative
vert_match1 = y[jump_idxs[0]] + deriv_match1
vert_shift1 = y[jump_idxs[0]+1] - vert_match1

vert_match2 = y[jump_idxs[2]] + deriv_match2
vert_shift2 = y[jump_idxs[2]+1] - vert_match2

## apply shift to data
y_shifted = np.copy(y)
y_shifted[jump_idxs[0]+1:jump_idxs[1]+1] = y_shifted[jump_idxs[0]+1:jump_idxs[1]+1] - vert_shift1
y_shifted[jump_idxs[2]+1:jump_idxs[3]+1] = y_shifted[jump_idxs[2]+1:jump_idxs[3]+1] - vert_shift2


##------------------
## METHOD 2
## match each side of the bad data individually, interpolate shifts
deriv_match1_1 = deriv[jump_idxs[1]+1]
deriv_match2_1 = deriv[jump_idxs[3]+1]

## find vertical shifts on other side of bad data
vert_match1_1 = y[jump_idxs[1]+1] + deriv_match1_1
vert_shift1_1 = y[jump_idxs[1]] - vert_match1_1

vert_match2_1 = y[jump_idxs[3]+1] + deriv_match2_1
vert_shift2_1 = y[jump_idxs[3]] - vert_match2_1

## interpolate shifts
y_shifted_1 = np.copy(y)
interp_shifts_1 = np.interp(np.arange(jump_idxs[0]+1,jump_idxs[1]+1), 
                            xp=[jump_idxs[0]+1,jump_idxs[1]+1],
                            fp=[vert_shift1,vert_shift1_1])
interp_shifts_2 = np.interp(np.arange(jump_idxs[2]+1,jump_idxs[3]+1), 
                            xp=[jump_idxs[2]+1,jump_idxs[3]+1],
                            fp=[vert_shift2,vert_shift2_1])
## apply shift to data
y_shifted_1[jump_idxs[0]+1:jump_idxs[1]+1] = y_shifted_1[jump_idxs[0]+1:jump_idxs[1]+1] - interp_shifts_1
y_shifted_1[jump_idxs[2]+1:jump_idxs[3]+1] = y_shifted_1[jump_idxs[2]+1:jump_idxs[3]+1] - interp_shifts_2


##------------------
## METHOD 3
## polynomial fit to data
good_data = np.copy(y)
good_locs = np.copy(x)
good_data = np.delete(good_data, np.arange(jump_idxs[2], jump_idxs[3]+2))
good_data = np.delete(good_data, np.arange(jump_idxs[0], jump_idxs[1]+2))
good_locs = np.delete(good_locs, np.arange(jump_idxs[2], jump_idxs[3]+2))
good_locs = np.delete(good_locs, np.arange(jump_idxs[0], jump_idxs[1]+2))

curve_fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(good_locs, good_data, deg=9))
x_fits = np.copy(x)
y_fits = []
for i in x_fits:
    y_fits.append(curve_fit(i))


##------------------
## PLOTS
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8,6))
twinx = ax[0,0].twinx()
ax[0,0].scatter(x, y, s=5)
ax[0,0].set(ylim=(-1, 3), ylabel="signal / curve", axisbelow=True)
twinx.plot(x[:-1], deriv, color='red', label="diff")
twinx.set_ylim(-5, 1)
twinx.set_ylabel("diff", rotation=270, labelpad=8)
ax[0,0].grid("both", alpha=0.2)
for idx in jump_idxs:
    ax[0,0].axvline(x[idx], ls=":", color="green")
    
    
ax[0,1].scatter(x, y_shifted, s=5, label="rectified data")
for idx in jump_idxs:
    ax[0,1].axvline(x[idx], ls=":", color="green")
ax[0,1].grid("both", alpha=0.2)
ax[0,1].set_title("Method 1")

ax[1,0].scatter(x, y_shifted_1, s=5, label="rectified data")
for idx in jump_idxs:
    ax[1,0].axvline(x[idx], ls=":", color="green")
ax[1,0].grid("both", alpha=0.2)
ax[1,0].set_title("Method 2")

ax[1,1].scatter(good_locs, good_data, s=5, zorder=10)
ax[1,1].plot(x_fits, y_fits, color="cyan", label='polynomial fit')
for idx in jump_idxs:
    ax[1,1].axvline(x[idx], ls=":", color="green")
ax[1,1].grid("both", alpha=0.2)
ax[1,1].set_title("Method 3")

twinx.legend()
ax[0,1].legend()
ax[1,0].legend()
ax[1,1].legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]